# How can I give options to users (time) and delete that option for the next user if it gets chosen?

Tags: php, html

I have this form as apart in my code:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="time">Time:</label></br>
            <select>
                <option value="0900">9:00</option>
                <option value="0915">9:15</option>
                <option value="0930">9:30</option>
                <option value="0945">9:45</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

It's a simple drop down that I might not need if there is another way to get what I want done.

Basically, I want these options for times, 9, 915, 930, 945, and I need them to not show up if the user selects that.

For example, if I select 9 and click submit, the next user will not see 9, only the other options.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need some sort of database to record the previously selected options. From there you can populate the dropdown with any options that haven't been previously selected.